# Extract email date issue - Google Script

Tags: getdate

I tried to extract email content and the sent date to GSheet using google script but I keep receiving error of
TypeError: message.getDate is not a function

My code as follows:

```
function extractDetails(message){

  var dateTime = message.getDate();

  var subjectText = message.getSubject();

  var senderDetails = message.getFrom();

  var bodyContents = message.getPlainBody();

  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Email');

  Sheet.appendRow([dateTime, senderDetails, subjectText, bodyContents]);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

// var dateTime = message.getDate();
var dateTime = Utilities.formatDate(message.getDate(), timezone, "dd-MM-yyyy");

try this

Comment: How would that fix it? Doesn't change the fact that `message.getDate` is not a function.